# How to remove uppercase text first word

Tags: css, text, blogger, uppercase

i want to ask

How to remove uppercase text first word

i have tried like this :

```
text-transform: none !important;
text-decoration : none !important;
```

not work

i'm using blogspot theme leading coral theme:

this my example web : https://blogkubagus123.blogspot.com/2020/02/testing-post.html

example like this screenshoot :

[image]

i want to change normal text (if i created bold they bold, if i created h1 they text h1,etc)

how to remove sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your page I found following style for `body.item-view .Blog .post-body::first-letter`

```
float:left;
font-size:80px;
font-weight:600;
line-height:1;
margin-right:16px;
```

So for cancel that you will need:

```
float:none;
font-size:inherit;
font-weight:inherit;
line-height:1;
margin-right:0;
```

All of those for the selector `body.item-view .Blog .post-body::first-letter` (less specific will not override the template style unless `!important` is used)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
body.item-view .Blog .post-body::first-letter{font-size:16px;}
```